# How to profile subprocesses line by line using memory-profiler

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, process, multiprocessing, memory-profiling

I would like to profile my code line by line and learn where my memory leak is happening.

A very impressive lib that does this is - [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/)

The command I want to replicate is `mprof run --include-children --multiprocess`

Which tracks my memory usage across processes.

But seems to only work if I use mprof which uses timestamps and memory over time, which allows me to graph the data as well, that is cool but I need to know where in my code this is happening.

Rather what I want is `python -m memory_profiler` with the args `--include-children --multiprocess`

Which doesn't seem supported. Unless there is another way, I think I am stuck here.

Is there a way to track the mem usage line by line when a subprocess launches another script/function.

I'm unsure if this has to do with the way I am using decorators and if I am using them wrong. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Fabian Pedregosa Any help here.

Comment: This is currently not supported. Pull requests are welcome but I don't think it would be easy to implement.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update here @FabianPedregosa